# Changing text color in Listview as the line of text is being displayed

Tags: autohotkey

I found references to changing text color but not with AutoHotKey. There seems to be a lot of LV modify options but nothing related to display color.

What I would like to do is to display a line of text in a color to be determined by one of the ListView column variable values as the line of text is put on screen.

Below is the some of the code. I've shortened the code for clarity but this should demonstrate what I want to do:

```
Gui, New ,, Basic List
Gui, Add, Text, x1, Location   %AppLocation%     Rec Count %NGCRec%
Gui, Add, ListView, VFirstGui H350 W256 gNGCSelect1 HScroll, Object Name|etc. etc
Gui, Add, Text,, Sort Options                 Siderial Time %SideHr%h etc. etc

While x < y
{
   ;If possible change text color here before the next line of text is displayed 
   LV_Add(, NGCSort%x%_11, NGCSort%x%_2, NGCSort%x%_5, NGCSort%x%_6, etc. etc)
   x += 1
}
```

Sorry for the double spacing above but other wise all the text wraps together

I know I can set listview colors in `Gui, Add, ListView, options` but those colors cannot be changed while the ListView text is being put on screen.

If it is not possible to change the Listview line colors as they are being displayed Could I possibly save the contents of the display variable in different colors?

The variables in the `LV_Add` statement are `NGCSort%x%_11`, `NGCSort%x%_2`, and so on.

The values in those variable are read in from a text file then displayed on screen as black text.

Is there a way to save the text file value into the `NGCSort%x%_%y%` variables in color so that they will display in color rather than trying to change the colors as the line of text is being put on the screen?

The idea behind this is to give the viewer an idea of how close an astronomical object is to its highest position in the sky. Blue, the object is rising toward its highest point. Red it is near its highest point. Green it is setting down and away from its highest point.

I am not a professional programmer, just a retired technician trying to work in the old BASIC spaghetti code. Not very pretty but it usually works. :)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you are attempting to shade a part or all of each row based on a value. I do not know how to achieve this, but I can offer an alternate solution.

AutoHotkey's ListView can display an icon at the start of each line. If you are not currently making use of these icons, you could achieve your purpose by changing the icons based on the value you choose.

#### From the AutoHotkey Documentation:

Link: [ListView - ImageList](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ListView.htm#IL)

> An Image-List is a group of identically sized icons stored in memory.
>   Upon creation, each ImageList is empty. The script calls IL_Add()
>   repeatedly to add icons to the list, and each icon is assigned a
>   sequential number starting at 1. This is the number to which the
>   script refers to display a particular icon in a row or column header.
>   Here is a working example that demonstrates how to put icons into a
>   ListView's rows:

```
Gui, Add, ListView, h200 w180, Icon & Number|Description  ; Create a ListView.
ImageListID := IL_Create(10)  ; Create an ImageList to hold 10 small icons.
LV_SetImageList(ImageListID)  ; Assign the above ImageList to the current ListView.
Loop 10  ; Load the ImageList with a series of icons from the DLL.
    IL_Add(ImageListID, "shell32.dll", A_Index) 
Loop 10  ; Add rows to the ListView (for demonstration purposes, one for each icon).
    LV_Add("Icon" . A_Index, A_Index, "n/a")
LV_ModifyCol("Hdr")  ; Auto-adjust the column widths.
Gui Show
return

GuiClose:  ; Exit the script when the user closes the ListView's GUI window.
ExitApp
```

#### Working Example

I have posted a working example as a [Gist here](https://gist.github.com/samthecodingman/44e58a47a0b2d07c8553f036285f5c4b) along with some different icon sets.

[image: Preview of Working Example]

Comment: A good alternative. I should be able to make a thin icon. This app will normally be used on screens with multiple apps running. Space is at a premium and there is a lot of info to display. Thank you

Comment: If you want to save yourself some work you can cheat by changing the width of the first column using `LV_ModifyCol(1, 8)` just below the `LV_SetImageList` call.